# Adding a new state via TFS Power Tools 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I'm attempting to use *Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools* to add a new state and transition to the `Task` Work Item Type. It's clear how to edit existing states and transitions but I haven't found a way to add either one. It would be simple to make the changes directly to the XML but the results of the 'View XML' feature are not editable.

[image: Workflow]

For context, my goal is to add an additional column to my agile task board in TFS. I'm following [an MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudiouk/2013/01/18/adding-additional-states-onto-the-agile-task-board-in-tfs2012/) that refers to adding a new state but doesn't specify how. That leads me to believe I'm just overlooking something simple, but I'm stumped..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the (unintuitive and easy to overlook) solution. Outside of the Work Item Types (WIT) pane there is a `Toolbox` tab that opens up a WITDesigner control panel. From there you can drag a State from the control panel into the WIT pane.

To make a transition link you must first select Transition Link in the control panel. You'll then move into the WIT pane where you must select the starting state, then select the state that's being transitioned to. Dragging the transition link is disabled.

[image]